# Ho do I add video to mosaic template mailing?

Tags: mosaico

I'm trying to create an email using a mosaico template and I want to add a video.  Is this possible?

Comment: Hi - can you clarify what you need. A link? An image with a link? You won't actually be 'sending' the video. Usually you would include an image with an "a href" around it taking folk to the url to view it.

Comment: Have you tried uploading the video on youtube and then use the embed code in your html?

Comment: Pete's comment is right in my view. Best to load the video to youtube or whatever, take a screenshot and use that as an image in your mosaico mail linked back to the youtube video. Inline embed tags invariably get stripped out by email clients or spam filters as they are a source of viruses and/or malware so will not work.